# Mobile - Media query for smaller screens applying for larger screens

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following media query for a **mobile** app,

```
only screen and (max-height: 630px) and (orientation: portrait) {}
```

What I want is for the styles inside this media query to apply to all screens which has a height of **630px or less**. Basically it should apply for smaller screens. On the browser this works great. But on actual devices, it doesn't work properly.

Devices which are larger than 630px still applies the styles inside that media query. I managed to fix it for **some** screens by adding the pixel ratio -

```
only screen and (max-height: 630px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

Still on some larger screens (even new phones) the styles are getting applied. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `device-height`

```
@media only screen 
and (max-device-height: 630px)
and (orientation: portrait)  {
        /* Code */
    }
```

A good article about media query https://blog.box.com/blog/media-queries-things-i-wish-id-known/

Comment: You mean max-device-height? I need the to apply the styles in that media query if the content I have is too long to fit the screen without having to scroll. That's why I want to use height. Also portrait because these are specific to portrait.

Comment: @user3607282 YES Same goes for height . Did you try it ?

Comment: @user3607282 Welcome and the reason it works I guess is that it's highly device specific.. Always try to use highly specific codes in any language to get higher control over things.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 630px){
     //Write your mobile styles here
}
```

Comment: Hi. Why have you removed the (orientation: portrait) part? Is there a reason?